# node-sass older version compatibility problems with node version 16

Tags: node.js, node-sass

I'm having an issue cloning this repo locally https://github.com/savajapurva/E-Learning-MERN. The problem is due to node-sass used is version 4.0.0 and is not compataible with my node v16.15.1. What shall I do?

When I install the latest node-sass I'm having this error `Error: Node Sass version 9.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.`

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The issue you're facing is due to a compatibility problem between the Node.js version you're using (v16.15.1) and the version of node-sass required by the project. To resolve this problem, you have a few options:

1. Use a compatible version of node-sass:
   Instead of installing the latest version of node-sass, you can try installing a specific version that is compatible with both your Node.js version and the project's requirements. You can check the project's package.json file or documentation to determine the compatible version. Then, install it using the --save-dev flag to update your project's dependencies.

`npm install node-sass@<compatible_version> --save-dev`

2. Update the project's dependencies:
   If the project's dependencies allow for it, you can try updating other dependencies to versions that are compatible with the latest version of node-sass. This might involve updating packages individually or upgrading the entire dependency tree. However, be cautious when upgrading dependencies, as it can introduce other compatibility issues or require additional code changes.
3. Downgrade your Node.js version:
   If possible, you can consider downgrading your Node.js version to one that is compatible with the project's dependencies. Check the project's documentation or the package.json file to see which Node.js versions are recommended or supported. You can use a version manager like nvm (Node Version Manager) to easily switch between different Node.js versions.
4. Use an alternative to node-sass:
   If the above options don't work, you can explore alternatives to node-sass, such as sass or dart-sass. These alternatives are pure JavaScript implementations of Sass, and they do not have any binary dependencies, eliminating compatibility issues. You can uninstall node-sass and install one of these alternatives instead. Remember to update the necessary build scripts or configurations to reflect the change in the build process.

Remember to carefully review the project's documentation and requirements to make the best decision regarding compatibility and dependencies.

Comment: Another copy-paste from ChatGPT

Comment: When you are pasting from Chat GRP atleast try to align the paragraph

Answer (score 0):

- Remove node-sass from package.json
- Execute npm install --force
- Then execute npm install node-saas

This would install the package without errors
If facing python error try installing python to your system